# Replacing values in a numpy 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

So I am reading in a 2D array from csv and converting it to a numpy array, like so:

```
sheet = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
sheet_data = sheet.as_matrix()
```

I can successfully replace values of 'N' and 'Y' in this 2D array with 0 and 1 respectively.

```
np.place(sheet_data, sheet_data == 'N', 0)
np.place(sheet_data, sheet_data == 'Y', 1)
```

However, the second and third column of this dataset are timestamps in the form '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', but I'm not sure how to use np.place to replace the values with the number of seconds since epoch.

In addition, some of these values are also recorded as NaN, but neither of these two lines successfully replaces them with 0:

```
np.place(taxi_sheet_data, taxi_sheet_data == 'nan', 0)
np.place(taxi_sheet_data, taxi_sheet_data == float('NaN'), 0)
```

How can I go about doing this?

The first item in sheet_data, as a reference, looks like this:

```
 [2 '2016-06-01 02:46:38' '2016-06-01 03:06:40' 0 1 -73.93058013916014
 40.695178985595696 -74.00005340576173 40.72904586791992 1 5.24 19.5 0.5
 0.5 6.24 0.0 nan 0.3 27.04 1 1.0]
```

Comment: Use `np.isnan()`?

Comment: Can't you do this in pandas?  That's supposed to have magical properties that numpy doesn't have. :)  But you really need to tell us the sh  Iape and dtype of the array.  I suspect it is an object dtype.